# Add a string to a specific location in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add a dot in the 4th position of each string in a column. How can I perform this in Postgres?

Example: `'1234'` should become `'123.4'`

Comment: These are codes and they can contain letters as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example use left / right:

```
db=> select left('1234', 3) || '.' || right('1234', -3);
 ?column? 
----------
 123.4
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you.